# What does it mean when saying "passing in something" in the following?| ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, pass-data

I was reading a book about Learning ASP.NET Core API when I run to a part saying:

> We call GetCommandByID on our repository **passing in** the Id from
> our route, storing the result in a local variable.

Here is some text I thought you'd better have:
[image]

Then there are some explanations related to the picture above:

> 1. The route to this controller action includes an additional route  parameter, in this case the Id of the resource we want to retrieve;
>    we can specify this in the HttpGet attribute as shown.
> 2. The controller action requires an id to be passed in as a  parameter (this comes from our route; see point 1) and returns an
>    ActionResult of type Command.
> 3. We call GetCommandByID on our repository **passing in the Id from our route**, storing the result in a local variable.
> 4. We check to see if our result is null and, if so, return a 404 Not  Found result.
> 5. Otherwise if we have a Command object, we return a 200 OK and  the result.

Now, I don't exactly know what the highlighted part above in number 3 mean?
Could I rewrite number 3 as follow:

> 3. We call GetCommandByID on our repository **which is submitting** the Id from our route, storing the result in a local variable.

If not, then Could anyone explain what the number 3 is saying to me?

Comment: You are **giving/passing/inputting to** the function/method, the **parameter** it needs to perform it designed function

Comment: I still have a problem well understanding it! would you complain a bit more?

Answer (score 3):

`GetCommandById(int id)` is a method that requires an `id` parameter.  The method name is `GetCommandById`.
When we call the method we must supply and `id` parameter.  We often refer to this as "passing in" the `id` parameter.  The method then has access to the `id` and can use it as part of the work it performs.  In this case the method ultimately returns an `ActionResult<Command>` object.

Answer (score 0):

Here,  `public ActionResult<Command> GetCommandById(int id)` It receives Id from the route as a query parameter. Then we call the  `GetCommandById(int id)` in the repository by passing id as a parameter which got from the route. Then the value which returns from the `GetCommandById(int id)` is stored in a variable called `CommandItem`.